# Adding exceptions on Ext.ajax requests Ext JS 6

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want to add 400, 500 exception for all the AJAX requests. Here is what I have done for `beforeload` on every AJAX request.

```
Ext.define('Inertia.view.BaseUrl', {
singleton : true,
constructor : function(config) {

    this.initConfig(config);
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', this.onBeforeRequest, this);
},

onBeforeRequest : function(connection, options) {
    options.headers = {
        'token': 'random-token',
        'code': 'random-codeABC'
    };
}

 });
```

Now I want to add an exception for all the requests, that if the request somehow didn't load I want to catch an exception. How would I do that 
I try this but it didn't work

```
Ext.define('Inertia.view.BaseUrl', {
singleton : true,
constructor : function(config) {

    this.initConfig(config);
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', this.onBeforeRequest, this);
    Ext.Ajax.on('exception', this.exception, this);
},

onBeforeRequest : function(connection, options) {
    options.headers = {
        'token': 'random-token',
        'code': 'random-codeABC'
    };
},
 exception: function (){
     alert('An Exception occured...!');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Why exactly isn't [`requestexception`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#event-requestexception) event enough? You can bind to it, check `response.status` and act accordingly.

Comment: I had a typo, i used `exception` instead of `requestexception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like below:-

```
/**
 * @ajaxrequest error handling
 */
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options, eOpts) {
    try {
        alert(response.status);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

**Or like this:-**

```
requestexception: function (conn, response, options, eOpts) {
    try {
        alert(response.status);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```